# ipython notebook don't open

Tags: ipython, ubuntu-15.10

I try to open ipython notebook but i get this message:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/ipython", line 5, in 
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 3080, in 
    @_call_aside

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 3066, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 3093, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 651, in _build_master
    ws.require(**requires**)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 952, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 839, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'traitlets' distribution was not found and is required by ipython

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to install this `traitlets` dependency ? : `pip install traitlets`

Comment: I get a new error 
>[Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 223, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 299, in run
    root=options.root_path]

Comment: This is very cryptic, like some error message is missing. Did you copy it entirely ? Does pip work for other packages ?